# Как в aiogram получить доступ с хранилищу сессии, чтобы там сохранять массив?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Смотрите, есть например 9 инлайн кнопок: "Один" "Два" "Три" "Четыре"...."Девять".
Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ее текст добавлялся в список, который потом выведу. Я добавляюю ее значение в список, но коллбек после отработки очищает список. Как это исправить?

Comment: Может быть, стоит попробовать НЕ очищать список после отработки коллбэка?

Comment: Вынести объявление списка из функции

Comment: может быть в этом и вопрос, как сделать, чтобы список не очищался? Выносить за функцию, ага, тогда бот будет работать некорректно

Comment: Создайте словарь { <user_id> : [список с текстом нажатых кнопок], 'time': <время устаревания> }
Ну дальше всё понятно...

Comment: @Виктор я возможно немного изначально неправильно пояснил, давайте я чуть подобнее опишу, может быть вы поймете: использую FSMContext, допустим есть ключ question, к которому я обращаюсь потом, чтобы получить его значение из state.get_data(), а как сделать, чтобы ключ question хранил не одно значение, а список значений? и чтобы потом, при обращении к нему, он выдавал мне список значений, которые я сохранил

Comment: Здесь описание https://zelenka.guru/threads/3769612/ тут пример https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html

Comment: @Виктор все по итогу прозаичнее, помог ваш ответ, который вы(?) удалили. async with state.proxy() as data:, я открыл его в хендлере, где задавал инлайн кнопки, там задал ключу data['question'] значение [] пустого списка. После чего в коллбеке я снова открывал менеджер контекста и значения начали добавляться.

Comment: @neo-noir Восстановил, тогда помечайте как принятый ответ и ещё жмите стрелку вверх :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доступ к state: FSMContext

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['mydata'] = message.text
```